# Lenovo ThinkPad T430 shows blank semi-transparent screen randomly

Tags: lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T430. I am facing a strange issue that even the local laptop technicians are not able to diagnose and resolve. The issue is that my laptop shows a blank semi-transparent screen at any time (during booting, after login or in middle of using the laptop). The laptop is not under warranty. I have got the motherboard checked, but the technician says motherboard is fine. It seems to be software issue so I replaced the hard disk with another one (which works well on other laptop), but I had no luck.

I am attaching two screenshots here, one before and the other after the blank screen.

[image]
<sup>**before**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**after**</sup>

I have tried rebooting machine multiple times, but I had no luck. Eventually after some time the laptop shuts down. I tried to run the shutdown command after screen goes blank, but nothing worked. I have to then hard reset and the same thing continues.

Comment: The nr. 1 thing to try would be an external screen. Did you already try that (my guess is that's what the technician did)? It could be that it's an issue with the screen's connector. One think you could try is boot the machine (such that you are sure there should be something on the screen). Then press down fairly hard around the 3 and the F-buttons above that. You are then pressing right above the screen's connector, which might help temporarily fix a dodgy contact.

Comment: Also, if you can find out what exactly the technician did, that would be a massive help. We cannot assume his diagnosis is correct as long as we don't know what he did.

Comment: I tried to press hard over 3 and F keys but no luck. And besides, if it is only the connector then it does not explain why laptop shuts down after some time

Comment: And yes I have tried attaching desktop monitor using vga cable but the result is same on monitor screen also.

Comment: It seems like you have a serious hardware issue then. Could you figure out what the technician did exactly? " I have got the motherboard checked but the technician says motherboard is fine". And indeed, the pushing test only makes sense if an external screen would've worked.

Comment: You should try running Lenovo's in-built hardware diagnostics tool: Repeatedly press F10 from the moment you turn the laptop on until you hear a beep and are greeted with the Lenovo Diagnostics screen. Use your arrow buttons to navigate to the 'Run all' button, then hit your enter key. Hit enter again, then again, and the tests will begin. It may take a while.

Comment: I did run Lenovo diagnostics. Although, it did not show anything like Run all but I did find Memory test and storage test. And during running memory test the screen freezed and then shutdown. One thing to note is that the screen color during the freeze is somewhat similar to majority of background. This time the background of diagnostic screen was green so the frozen screen was green, nothing was visible and nothing was working. Eventually, laptop shut down.